# Spring MVC application add stock to cart jsp JAVA

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to write simple web app with some stock which can be added to cart. I will copy the code and jsp files. I hope i am in right direction for solving this problem. I take the data from database. For now i want to show what is added to cart and later i will try to save it in db.

Full stack trace.

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/cart.jsp at line 14

11:     <div style="padding-right: 40px">
12:         <table border="1">
13:             <tr>
14:                 <c:forEach items="${cpu}" var="c">
15:                     <td>Name</td>
16:                     <td>${c.name}</td>
17:                 </c:forEach>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.cart_jsp._jspService(cart_jsp.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.cart_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(cart_jsp.java:178)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.cart_jsp._jspService(cart_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
```

**cart.jsp**

```
<body>
    <div style="padding-right: 40px">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach items="${cpu}" var="c">
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>${c.name}</td>
                </c:forEach>



    </div>
```

**Controller**
@Controller

```
public class CartController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someAction(@ModelAttribute("cpu") Cpu cpu, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("cpu", cpu);
        return "cart";
    }
}
```

**Cpu**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Cpu implements Serializable {

    public static final String SESSION_PROPERTY = "cpu";

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String socket;

    private int price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public void setSocket(String socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can track the error all the way from "Don't know how to iterate over supplied items" to your `Cpu` type which evidently doesn't implement `Iterable`. Impossible to know, since this is the only bit of code you decided *not* to include.

Comment: @kryger I have added cpu class.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate using `<c:forEach>` over a single instance of your custom `Cpu` type, while the obvious requirement for iteration is... to have a collection of objects that you can iterate over. This is what the JSTL specification says:

> A large number of collection types are supported by `<c:forEach>`, including all implementations of java.util.Collection (includes List, LinkedList, ArrayList, Vector, Stack, Set), and java.util.Map (includes HashMap, Hashtable, Properties, Provider, Attributes).
>
> (...)
>
> Implementations of java.util.Iterator and java.util.Enumeration are
>   supported as well (...).

Your controller should be changed to create a `List<Cpu>` that would be later passed to the JSP page via a model attribute. A common idiom for implementing a cart in an online store is to use a `HttpSession` to accumulate all user's items. Later on you can access this shared session object in the `CartController` and retrieve all the items user put there.

Comment: You were already dealing with this problem a week ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36682201/1240557. If there's some basic concept you don't understand you should refer to the official documentation or tutorials from a reputable source, not just "try everything until it works".